# No more OpenGLES 2 UWP template in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: cross-platform, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, a convenient cross-platform C++ project template was available named "OpenGLES 2 Application (Android, iOS, Windows Universal)."  I cannot find this template in Visual Studio 2017; only the Android + iOS template is present.

[A response to this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31899/where-is-the-visual-c-opengles-2-application-andro.html) on the VS dev community site suggests the template was removed by design.  If so, are there any alternatives I might consider to give a similarly streamlined workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dig up the template from a prior VS version and move it forward; it might take a bit of tweaking, but it should work. The built-in templates are in the VS installation directory, for example, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates`

You could also use VS 2015 to create an instance of that template you want to use, and then manually [turn that project into a custom template for your own use](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/adding-project-and-project-item-templates).

The new project dialog also has a place where you can search for templates in an online database of community contributions (kind of like the add-on community options), so you may be able to find yourself a suitable template there.

If none of the above are options, simply use VS to create a new instance of that template, save that created project structure off someplace, and copy or clone it when you want to make a new project. The poor man's template, as it were.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer; it's totally sound and generally good information.  In my case, I ended up just going back to VS 2015 because I was having so many headaches with this.